# Laravel with webpack , VueJs and Vue-route

Tags: webpack, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-router

I refereed so many tutorials related webpack , VueJs and Vue-Route but all tutorials are individual. I was searching for tutorials that explain/show Laravel with Webpack , VueJs and Vue-route together but bad luck.

Individually , I worked with webpack , VueJs for html template not with Vue-route.

> My project requirement is :

- **Use Lumen for back-end (APIs)**
- **Use Laravel , VueJs and Vue-Route for front side (Web)**
- **Use WebPack for .Js , .css , .sass And Images type (bundal.js, you know wnat I mean)**

> What I have done so far :

- **Set up Lumen platform for Apis**
- **Set up laravel for front**

Now , I need/want to set up webpack , VueJs and Vue-route with laravel framework. At this point I'm confuse.

> I have few questions related my confusion.

1. **How to set up webpack with Laravel.**
2. **How to use VueJs and Vue-route with Laravel Route.**

For above 2 questions my mind is blank. what to do next and how to do? Don't have any idea.

So if any one can explain how to work with Laravel , Webpack , VueJs and Vue-Route with example it would be grate.

Answer (score 1):

well when you install a new laravel application laravel already comes with webpack installed and with easy to use **laravel-mix installed**..

All you have to do is on server side in **laravel** go to your routes file
catch all the urls and let it handle by the vue just like this.

```
 Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('any' , ".*");
```

now your every request is going to serve the `index.blade.php` page and the vue-router will handle the url and serve the specifig component for that route

then go to your cmd install the dependencies like `npm install vue-router -save` etc 
after installing your desired dependencies.

i am asuming probably you already know how to use vue router on its own
go to app.js file write all your `vue` and `vue-router` code here for example

```
    import Vue from 'vue';

    window.axios = require('axios');    
   Vue.prototype.$http = axios;

  import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
  import home from './components/pages/home.vue'
  import App from './App.vue'

  Vue.use(VueRouter);

 let routes = [
    {
        path :'/',
        name :'home',
        component : home
    },
]

let Router =  new VueRouter({
    routes : routes,
    mode : 'history'
})


    const app = new Vue({
        el : '#app',
        router : Router,
        render : h => h(App)
    });
```

at the end run `npm run dev` script in the cmd. serve the generated `js` file to the `index.blade.php` **the page your server serves on every request**

as we are supplying the `el : #app` to the vue to make a `div` with an id of `#app` in the `index.blade.php` and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

> So if you have Lumen for backend and everything is ok...then use Lumen and Vue.js separately.It would be great and has some advantages.
>
> Leave Lumen as it is and create a new vue.js application.Then install vue-router
>   and you are done.